# What are the pros and cons of having an update source be a reference member instead of passing it to the update functions?

Tags: c++

I have a class whose instance relies completely on updates from an instance of a separate class.
Simplified example:

```
#include "Source.h"

class ObjectThatNeedsUpdates
{
public:
    ObjectThatNeedsUpdates();
    void update(const Source& source)
    {
        //Update member data with data from source
    }
private:
    //Some member data that needs updating
};
```

As you can see, every time I call the update function I pass a const reference of the Source class. But recently I thought that maybe it would be more logical to pass the reference to the Source object only once when a ObjectThatNeedsUpdates is constructed and let the class store the reference as a member, to avoid having to pass the source every time I want to update the object.

As such:

```
#include "Source.h"

class ObjectThatNeedsUpdates
{
public:
    ObjectThatNeedsUpdates(const Source& source)
      : source_(source)
    {
    }
    void update()
    {
        //Update member data with data from source_
    }
private:
    const Source& Source_;
    //Some member data that needs updating
};
```

What are the pros and cons of this approach?

Comment: First off, pros and cons versus what approach? Also, a question like this could be considered opinion based. Are there any specific concerns you have about this approach?

Comment: Whenever you are thinking of using a reference data member, you are almost always better off using a pointer data member instead. Using a reference data member disables compiler generated assignment, and it is often not possible to implement them yourself correctly. Similar reasoning applies to using `const` data members. It is usually better to implement them as `private` non-`const` data members and maintaining invariance through the interface.

Comment: a reference parameter may be a bit more elegant in terms of internal encapsulation: only `update()` method needs this? - no need to expose this as a member for other methods. No worries in terms of changes of `Source`. Difference in performance (comparing to a member) negligible. Whereas if you engage a `shared_ptr` which is costly you contradict your own motivation in the first place...

Comment: @bloody I thought there was almost no difference performance-wise between pointers and references?

Comment: @cigien What approach do you think? Maybe the one I presented in my question?

Comment: Ok, maybe I didn't fully understand what you were asking about. My bad.

Comment: @cigien No worries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do whatever you feel best expresses the contract between the caller of `update()` and the class itself.

If the lifetime of `ObjectThatNeedsUpdates` is always contained within the lifetime of the `Source` object, and which `Source` object to use never changes, then I feel that holding a reference to the `Source` object is the best expression of the contract.

Although, consider holding a `std::shared_ptr` instead.  That'll better protect you from lifetime problems.

Performance-wise, passing a reference as an argument to a function is extremely cheap (same cost as passing a pointer, which is usually the same cost as passing a `size_t`).

Comment: Hadn't thought about the lifetime problems that could arise. Thanks, I will change it to a shared_ptr